# Making sense out of docker create command line arguments

Tags: docker

I am trying to understand the following `docker create` command from the book [Docker in Action 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617294764):

```
docker container create --name export-test dockerinaction/ch7_packed:latest ./echo For Export
```

Here we are creating a container named `export-test` that will be used to run the image `dockerinaction/ch7_packed:latest`.  So far so good.

---

**What does the `./echo For Export` part in the above command do?**

The online documentation for [docker create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/) does not yield any clue to me.

Comment: First stop: The documentation for [`docker create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/).

Comment: #tadman it is somewhat condescending to assume that I did not look up the docker create documentation.

Comment: Don't take it personally. Establishing where you're at is an important first step and in your explanation there was no clue you'd gotten that far. That command is run on the container during the creation process, though I'm not sure how an `echo` would be useful. Maybe it's just to demo the concept?

Comment: There is nothing condescending in @tadman's comment. You've made no mention of reading the documentation or explaining what part of that documentation isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It specifies the command that will get run when you eventually `docker start` the container.  It overrides the `CMD` in the image's Dockerfile.  If the image has an `ENTRYPOINT` then [the command will be passed to the entrypoint command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) as command-line arguments.